# How will "Final" closing down affect my credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

I recently opened up a new credit card with a company called "Final". That company has decided to close down (they did not go into details on why). In response to this, I have 2 questions:

1) How will this closure affect my credit score?

2) If this negatively affects my credit score, is there anything I can do to minimize that?

**Update:**

In response to RonJohn's answer, I wanted to provide [the public source](https://getfinal.com/company-news/2017/12/06/a-final-farewell/) for where "Final" has communicated that it is shutting down.

Included as a screenshot for when the webpage is taken down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find no mention of Final closing down in Google.  Anyway, it's issued by an actual bank (First Bank & Trust of Brookings, SD), and the bank isn't going out of business.  Thus, I'd suspect they'd convert you to a standard Visa.

Even if they don't, closed accounts have a minimal, temporary impact on your score.